# How to filter a form based on a DateTimeField using timedelta

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following model for Sessions:

courses/models.py:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course_date_start = models.DateTimeField()
    course_date_end = models.DateTimeField()
    is_in_session = True

    def session_id(self):
        new_session_date = self.course_date_start.strftime('%Y')
        return f'{new_session_date}{self.course.number}{self.pk}'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.course.number} - {self.course.title} - {self.session_id()}'
```

And in my users/forms.py:

```
class EnrollStudentInCourseForm(forms.Form):
    global roster_limit
    student = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Student.objects.all())
    courses=SessionRemainingSlotsForm(queryset=Session.objects.annotate(num_students=Count('student')).filter(num_students__lt=roster_limit))
```

I'd like to filter out the fields so that it only shows sessions where `course_date_start` plus a week, to cover a student joining the class a little late.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was messing up my math because I solved it:

What I did was use the `timedelta` function in my form filter to to only show sessions that are still within the cutoff date:

```
courses = SessionRemainingSlotsForm(queryset=Session.objects.annotate
(num_students=Count('student')).filter(course_date_start__gte=date.today() - timedelta(days=7),
                                       num_students__lt=roster_limit))
```